# Create Settings Page

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

How to create settings switchers in Ionic2 app for push notification and sound notifications.

Considering code below from ionic cloud services for push notification, I am assuming that I have to save booleans in localstorage

`const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
    'app_id': 'APP_ID',
  },
  'push': {
    'sender_id': 'SENDER_ID',
    'pluginConfig': {
      'ios': {
        'badge': true,
        'sound': true
      },
      'android': {
        'iconColor': '#343434'
      }
    }
  }
};`

I don't really know where to begin. Docs are not clear on this. https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register and unregister device token to make it work.